# Column to row with rename Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I have a large table that looks like the following:

```
section  term  percentageyr_1   percentageyr_2  percentageyr_3 ... percentageyr_25  
01          1         0.1              0.9           0.3                0.6     
01          2         0.3              0.5           0.01               0.3
01          3         0.6              0.4           0.2                0.6
01          4         0.3              0.5           0.7                0.14                  
01          5         0.4              0.2           0.6                0.6                           
            .
            .
            .
            .
            20

02          1         0.3              0.5           0.5                0.8
02          2         0.9              0.1           0                  0.6
.
.
.
20
```

I need to create a new table that looks more like the following:

```
year | section | term | percent
--------------------------------
1         01       1       0.1
2         01       1       0.9
3         01       1       0.3
.         01       1        .
20        01       1       0.6
1         01       2       0.3
2         01       2       0.5
.         01       2       0.01
.         01       2
20        01       2       0.3
...
1         01       20
2         01       20   
.         01       20
.         01       20
20        01       20
1         02       1
2         02       1    
.         02       1
.         02       1
.         02       1
20        02       1 
etc.
```

I have seem some similar examples doing the opposite transformation using decode() but I'm not sure about the column -> row direction and how I can change the name of the columns in transition.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your goal your output or are you trying to transform your existing table?  If your goal is your output above, try something like this:

```
SELECT r.r year, t.section, t.term
FROM LargeTable t, (
    SELECT Rownum r
    FROM dual
    CONNECT By Rownum <= 20 ) r
ORDER BY t.section, t.term, r.r
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/120f3/2).

--EDIT

Given your edits, you could still use the following (I only used a couple columns, but you should get the idea), and add a `CASE` statement for your percentages:

```
SELECT r.r year, t.section, t.term,
   CASE 
      WHEN r.r = 1 THEN percentageyr_1
      WHEN r.r = 2 THEN percentageyr_2
      WHEN r.r = 25 THEN percentageyr_25
   END as percent
FROM LargeTable t, (
    SELECT Rownum r
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY Rownum <= 25 ) r
    ORDER BY t.section, t.term, r.r
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f76b/1).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was exactly what I was looking for! Do you know if the case when block can be replaced with an if or for loop as there are actually 40 percent columns. Sorry for the additional question, I'm only starting to learn SQL at the minute and not too sure what is and isn't allowed!

Answer (score 1):

This type of transformation is actually an *unpivot*.  Oracle 10g does not have an unpivot function, but you can use a `UNION ALL`to transform the data from columns into rows:

```
select percentageyr_1 year, section, term
from yourtable
union all
select percentageyr_2 year, section, term
from yourtable
union all
select percentageyr_3 year, section, term
from yourtable
union all
select percentageyr_25 year, section, term
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1392/1)

Edit, based on your changes, you should be able to use the following to *unpivot* the data:

```
select 1 year, section, term, percentageyr_1 percent
from yourtable
union all
select 2 year, section, term, percentageyr_2
from yourtable
union all
select 3 year, section, term, percentageyr_3
from yourtable
union all
select 25 year, section, term, percentageyr_25
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1392/2)

Comment: Given the OP's edits, this could also work by adding a column to each union, something like SELECT '1' as Year, section, term, percentageyr_1 as Perc...

Comment: @sgeddes correct, I just edit my answer to incorporate the OP's edits.